# Send method in new Vue is not called when form is submitted

Tags: socket.io, vue.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>  
    <meta charset=" UTF-8">
    <title> Document</title>
</head>

<body id="chat">    

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.5.0/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.min.js"></script>

    <form v-on="submit: send">  
            <input v-model="message"> 

            <button>Send</button>
    </form>



    <script>
        var socket  = io();

        new Vue({
            el: '#chat',

            date: {
                message: ''
            },

            methods: {
                send: function(e)
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert("a");


                }
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

I want to call the send method defined in new Vue when the form is submitted ,
But when i submit the form, page is reloading.

I have created a Vue object and linked it to the chat element.

I guess e.preventDefault() is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, I just helped somebody with a similar issue, the syntax for Vue.2.0 is `v-on:submit="send"` not `v-on="submit: send"`. Vue already has a way stop the form submitting which is: `v-on:submit.prevent` so you don't need the `e.preventDefault`, you would get:

```
<form v-on:submit="send" v-on:submit.prevent>
```

or a shorter version:

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="send">
```

There are a few more issues here, so I will go through them for you:

Firstly, you are never submitting the form. To submit a form you need a submit input, not a button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
```

However, from what I can see it's likely you don't even need a form, and can simply use a button with v-on:click:

```
<div>
    <input v-model="message"> 
    <button v-on:click="send">Send</button>
</div>
```

And then get what was submitted from the view model:

```
   send: function()
   {
      alert(this.message);
   }
```

You should also use the console (under developer tools in your browser) and log any output rather than alert (`console.log(this.message)`), because it will also sniff out any general errors with your code - for example I can see that you also have a typo (the same one I always make) it's dat**a** not dat**e**:

```
   data: {
        message: ''
    },
```

Comment: <form v-on:submit="send" v-on:submit.prevent> 
    <input v-model="message"> 

    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
  </form>
   
  
  
  <script>
   var socket = io();

   new Vue({
    el: '#chat',

    data: {
     message: ''
    },

    methods: {
     send: function(e)
     {
      console.log(this.message);
      
      
     }
    }
   })
  </script>

Comment: I changed my code, but the form is still being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what about this

```
<form  @submit.prevent="send">  
    <input v-model="message"> 
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

And then you can remove preventing default browser action from your `send()` method

Comment: <form @submit.prevent="send"> 
    <input v-model="message"> 

    <button>Send</button>
  </form>
   
  
  
  <script>
   var socket = io();

   new Vue({
    el: '#chat',

    date: {
     message: ''
    },

    methods: {
     send: function(e)
     {
      alert("a");
      
      
     }
    }
   })
  </script>
 </body>